# Joining parts of a numeric array in VBA

Tags: vba

My NUMERIC array is A (0 To 99).

I want to delete the tenth element A (9) and put the two parts A (0 To 8) and A (10 To 99) together into A (0 To 98).

This is a simplification of the real case, where deleting of different elements is done many times inside a loop, and the array contains more than 300 000 elements, so execution time is of importance.
How can this be solved in an efficient way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If inserts/deletes occur very often then perhaps an array is not the correct data structure look at Dictionaries. But we need to know more about your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Collection:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As New Collection

    c.Add "a"
    c.Add "b"
    c.Add "c"
    c.Add "d"

    c.Remove 2

    For Each ch In c
        Debug.Print ch
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What if there is more than one dimension?                         My values are placed in columns A - G in a worksheet with more than 300 000 rows. How can I assign the values to a collection, so that it is possible to work with the elements like it was an array?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of columns?

Comment: My array: Dim A(0 To 367907, 0 To 6) as Integer.

Comment: Ok, you could use a collection containing arrays with six elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Test()

```
Dim A(6) As New Collection ' 7 arrays
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To 367907
    A(0).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
    A(1).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 2)
    A(2).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 3)
    A(3).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 4)
    A(4).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 5)
    A(5).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 6)
    A(6).Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 7)
xt i
```

End Sub

Comment: What is wrong with the code above? ("Ne" is missing from "Next i")

Answer (score 0):

This code works for assigning values to collA, but what is wrong vith the Remove statement?
I want to remove collA(1)(9, 0), collA(1)(9, 1), collA(1)(9, 2), collA(1)(9, 3), collA(1)(9, 4), collA(1)(9, 5) and collA(1)(9, 6).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim A() As Integer
    Redim A(0 To 367907, 0 To  6) As Integer

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 367907
    For j = 0 To 6    
        A(i, j) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
    Next j
    Next i

    Dim collA As VBA.Collection

    Set collA = New Collection
    collA.Add A

    Erase A

    collA(1).Remove 10

End Sub
```